# error when insert long text in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, codeigniter-3

I work in codeigniter and I have this error

```
{"error_string":["\u062d\u0642\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0624\u0644\u0641 \u0641\u0627\u0631\u063a","\u062d\u0642\u0644 \u0639\u0646\u0648\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0648\u0631\u0642\u0629 \u0641\u0627\u0631\u063a","\u062d\u0642\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0644\u062e\u0635 \u0641\u0627\u0631\u063a"],"inputerror":["author","title","abstract"],"status":false}
```

when I insert long text in textarea , when I insert short text it worked
and when I insert from localhost it worked but in my server in internet not worked and in php.ini 
memory_limit = 256M
post_max_size = 128M

Comment: I think you need to change database field type from varchare(255) to Text() or Longtext().

Comment: did u checked live database table's column length in which you are inserting long text ?